# how to set -3years from current date and +9months from the current date in JQUERY in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, html

[image]

Hey Iam using html5 date attribute and it needs some Restriction from past Year And Future Dates **Dynamically** by having todays current date / year.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ncto3zjk/1/)**

- -3 years from current date
- +9 months from the current month

Example :

current year is 2015-3 = 2012 + 9 months

**JS :**

```
var checkUserAgent = navigator.userAgent;
      // if (checkUserAgent.match(/iPad/i) || checkUserAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
            $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
            var checkBabyId1 = $('#babys_due_date_id').length > 0;
            if (checkBabyId1 == true) {

                // logic for 9 months 
                var myMonths = 9;
                var CurrentDate = new Date();
                CurrentDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth() + myMonths);

                console.log(CurrentDate) // adding 9 months 

                // logic for - 3 years
                var myPastYears = 3;
                var CurrentYear = new Date();
                CurrentYear.setYear(CurrentYear.getYear() - myPastYears )
                console.log(CurrentYear) // - 3years


                $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
                $('#babys_due_date_id.date-padding label').hide();
                $('#babys_due_date_id')
                .find('input')
                .prop({
                    /*'readonly':'true', */
                    'type':'date'/*,
                    'min' : '2012-01-01',
                    'max' : '2016-12-01'*/
                })
                .css({ 
                    'border':'1px solid #f00 !important',
                    'width':'200px','margin-top':'10px' 
                });

                $('#babys_due_date_id label').on('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
                });

                $('#babys_due_date_id-datepicker-popup-0').on('click', function(){
                    $('#ui-datepicker-div').remove();
                    $('#ui-datepicker-div').datepicker( "option", "disabled", true );
                });
            }
      // }
```

Answer (score 1):

use the minDate option:

```
$('#ui-datepicker-div').datepicker( "option", "minDate", "-3y +9m");
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

or:

```
<script>
  var now = new Date();
    var year = now.getFullYear() - 3;
    var month = now.getMonth() - 8; // jan = 0
    if (month < 0) {
      month = 11 + month;
      year++;
    }

  $('#datepicker').attr("min", year+'/'+month+'/'+now.getDate());
</script>
```

for simple `<input type="date">`

Comment: Thanks, but Iam using iPhone Default Date Picker <input type="date" />, i can add min & max, but this will be hardcoded one, i need auto adjustable

Comment: you could fill in the min/max date with javascript

Comment: i added a 2nd version

Comment: Did this answers your question?